# How to resolve 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted' error in on_audio_query plugin?"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

E/AndroidRuntime(14341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14341): Process: com.example.hibiki, PID: 14341
E/AndroidRuntime(14341): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:435)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:263)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at com.lucasjosino.on_audio_query.queries.AudioQuery$querySongs$1.invokeSuspend(AudioQuery.kt:67)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7975)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
E/AndroidRuntime(14341):        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@3d6edb7, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]

this is player_controller.dart

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:on_audio_query/on_audio_query.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class PlayerController extends GetxController {
  final audioQuery = OnAudioQuery();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    checkPermission();
  }
  
  checkPermission() async {
    var perm = await Permission.storage.request();
    if(perm.isGranted){
    } else{
      checkPermission();
    }
  }
}
```

this is home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hibiki/const/colors.dart';
import 'package:hibiki/const/text_style.dart';
import 'package:hibiki/controllers/player_controller.dart';
import 'package:on_audio_query/on_audio_query.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    var controller = Get.put(PlayerController());
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bgDarkColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: bgDarkColor,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: whiteColor,
                )),
          ],
          leading: const Icon(Icons.sort_rounded, color: whiteColor),
          title: Text("Hibiki",
              style: ourStyle(
                size: 18,
              )),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<SongModel>>(
          future:  controller.audioQuery.querySongs(
            ignoreCase: true,
            orderType: OrderType.ASC_OR_SMALLER,
            sortType: null,
            uriType: UriType.EXTERNAL
          ),
         builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.data == null) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }else if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty){
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                "No Songs Found",
              style: ourStyle(),
              ),
            );
          }else{
           return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                  child: ListTile(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14)),
                    tileColor: bgColor,
                    title: Text(
                      "Music name",
                      style: ourStyle(size: 15),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "Artist name",
                      style: ourStyle(size: 12),
                    ),
                    leading: const Icon(
                      Icons.music_note,
                      color: whiteColor,
                      size: 32,
                    ),
                    trailing: const Icon(
                      Icons.play_arrow,
                      color: whiteColor,
                      size: 26,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            );
          }
         },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

someone help please